# Summing objects in recursive python function

Tags: python, function, recursion, sum

I need to sum objects (strings, ints, etc.) in one function (**don't** create other function, it can be done within one). It should work this way: When given `my_sum([[['s'],'ta'],['c',['k']]])`, it should return `'stack'`.

I came up with this:

```
def my_sum(array):

    if not array: #empty array
        return None

    else:

        for item in array:

            if type(item) == list:
                my_sum(item)

            else:
                print(item)
```

It of course is not doing what it should be, I was just playing around with it trying to come up with something. This code above returns this:

```
s
ta
c
k
```

I think I am not that far from result as I have what I need, but here is the problem how can I sum up those items ? I can't write `result = ''` anywhere in the function and then `return` it, because it would be deleting every time there would be recursion call. Also I don't want `global` variables (if anyone would think of that). Maybe I am just being stupid and can't see that it is one simple thing, pardon me if it is so.

Thank you for every answer!

Comment: I got a deja-vu here.

Comment: You need another argument to your `my_sum` function, try an accumulator value so that instead of returning `None` you can return that value.  `def my_sum(array, acc=None): ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common accumulating pattern is:

```
result = <init value>
for item in argument:
     result = result <operator> item
return result
```

(this can be written more concisely, but that's not the point for now).

Applied to your problem:

```
def my_sum(items):
    result = ''
    for item in items:
        if type(item) == list:
            result += my_sum(item)
        else:
            result += item
    return result
```

Note that `type(x) == y` is frowned upon in Python, [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) is considered better style.

Homework: extend the function so that it works for these arguments too:

```
print my_sum([[['s'],'ta'],('c',('k')), {('over'), ('flow')}])
```

Comment: And even then, `isinstance` should be use sparingly, as it will, for example, fail if the input is a `tuple` even though it would be perfectly valid (as your followup question is designed to point out, I assume)